# Is the GTN the only way to get older pack items in SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I recently started playing Star Wars: The Old Republic, but the game's been online for something like 3 years. I enjoy collecting the Cartel packs, but currently only the Shadow packs are available in the store.

**Is the in-game GTN (galactic trade network, aka auction house) the only way to find these older pack items?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older packs have occasionally been brought back to the Cartel Market for short periods.  There have also been special Crystal, Vehicle, etc. packs which gather together items from several previous packs.

There are also Cartel Reputation vendors in the Cartel Bazaar area (North elevator on the Republic Fleet, and South elevator on the Imperial fleet) which offer a subset of older pack items in addition to a few unique ones.

There's also direct trading with someone who has the items, but generally it will be easier to look on the GTN.

Comment: Thanks - that's pretty much what I expected. I didn't know about the cartel rep vendor, though, so definitely +1 for that alone.

Comment: @Omegacron just as an example; last christmas/newyears period, they put the older packs online for a few days; one kind per day for a few days;

Comment: @Vahx - good to know, I'll keep an eye out. I've only been playing about 3 weeks now, but I have a feeling I'll be sticking around.

Answer (score 0):

those fleet vendors you need rep with them to buy the items off, and the only way to get the rep is with rep tokens from the old packs.  Its totally a fruitless situation since you have to have millions of credits to buy the older packs off gtn.  the new alliance packs don't have any rep tokens in them which is stupid.

Comment: Welcome on Arqade. You can give an answer to a question, but you shouldn't share your opinion over things like this on this website. This is mainly a question/answer thing, not a site where we share our opinion.